# Maven Exception : Result too large

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm getting the following strange exception when running my maven build. Has anyone experienced similar? This started happening out of the blue. I've tried clean building as well as using -U.

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  7.688 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-05-25T13:03:41+10:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:unpack (download data migration cmd) on project platform-data-management: Error unpacking file: C:\Users\na\.
m2\repository\com\pro\platform\migration-cmd\1.8.0-SNAPSHOT\migration-cmd-1.8.0-SNAPSHOT.zip to: C:\workspace\pro\data-management\target\migration
[ERROR] org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: Error while expanding C:\Users\na\.m2\repository\com\migration-cmd\1.8.0-SNAPSHOT\migration-cmd-1.8.0-SNAPSHOT.
zip: Result too large
```

Comment: I guess this zip archive is somehow broken.

Comment: run with mvn -e -X to see the full stack trace

Comment: I strongly recommend to turn on checksum policy to prevent download issues ... Also see https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/ furthermore I would ask why do you use maven-dependency-plugin:unpack?

Comment: @khmarbaise Sorry, I'm new to maven. Is unpack not appropriate? What would be better suited for this?

Comment: @JFabianMeier I can manually unzip it though

Comment: I need much more information about the project or even better a link to the project...to what you are trying to achive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it just started working. How strange.